# .htaccess query string redirect with same value

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect URLs with a query string to another query string using .htaccess

**From:** `https://example.com/?smp=123456` (Any number after =)

**To:** `https://example.com/?p=123456` (Same number as in From URL)

I tried following but it's not working.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?smp=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/?p=$ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: The query string does not start with `/?`. Only the part _after_ the question mark, constitutes the query portion of an HTTP URL.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^/?smp=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
> RewriteRule ^$ https://www.example.com/?p=$ [R=301,L]
> ```

The main problem here is that you are not using the captured value of the URL parameter from the preceding *condition* (`RewriteCond` directive). The `%1` backreference holds this value. The `$` at the end of the *substitution* string would be seen as a literal `$`.

Also...

- the query string does not start with a `/`, so the `/?` part (optional slash) in the regex is superfluous.
- you are redirecting to `www.example.com`, but your example uses `example.com` (the domain apex). If you simply want to redirect to the same hostname (and *scheme*) then the scheme+hostname can be omitted. However, in order to minimise canonical redirects then it should stay.
- `[0-9]` can be shortened to `\d`.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^smp=(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://example.com/?p=%1 [R=301,L]
```

This would need to go near the top of the root `.htaccess` file.