# .htaccess remove specific query string part from URL and redirect query string with same value

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect URLs with a query string to another query string while removing `&anyParameterName=anyValue` **after the first query string** in the From URL using .htaccess

`&anyParameterName=anyValue` could be anything.

If someone visit `https://example.com/?id=123456&anyParameterName=anyValue` , First htaccess should remove the `&anyParameterName=anyValue` part from the URL and then redirect it as given below.

**From:** `https://example.com/?id=123456&anyParameterName=anyValue` (Any number after id=)

**To:** `https://example.com/?p=123456` (Same number as in id= of the From URL)

I have a code but it has no option to remove `anyParameterName=anyValue` (Any Parameter with Any Value)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?p=%1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: You are trying to match a query string that contains _only_ `id=...`, and nothing else. So for the example URL you want to rewrite, that condition does not apply, and so no redirect happens.

Answer (score 0):

This is really just an extension of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76069219/htaccess-query-string-redirect-with-same-value).

> If someone visit `https://example.com/?id=123456&anyParameterName=anyValue`, **First htaccess should remove** the `&anyParameterName=anyValue` part from the URL and then redirect it as given below.

You are perhaps thinking about this issue the wrong way. Instead of "first removing the other params", you just need to make sure you are matching the `id` URL parameter, regardless of whether there are other URL parameters that follow in the query string. Currently you are matching query strings that consist of only the `id` URL parameter. The new URL you construct in the *substitution* string (2nd argument to the `RewriteRule` directive) then only sets the URL parameter you are interested in.

Your existing *condition* that captures the value of the `id` URL parameter:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)$ [NC]
> ```

The trailing `$` is the end-of-string anchor, so it only matches when `id=<number>` occurs at the end of the query string. (Likewise, the `^` only matches when `id=<number>` is at the start of the query string. In other words, the regex only matches when that is the only URL parameter in the query string.)

You need to match either the end-of-string, OR a `&` that delimits the next URL parameter. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=([0-9]+)($|&) [NC]
```

The `$|&` part is regex *alternation*. One of the parts separated by `|` (pipe symbol) must match. The surrounding parentheses enclose this regex token (but also makes it a capturing group).

Now, any URL parameters that follow the `id=<number>` URL parameter in the query string are discarded.

If you also wanted to discard any URL params that might occur *before* the `id` parameter then you need a similar thing at the start of the regex. In this case it's either `^` (start-of-string) or `&` (URL param delimiter). For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=([0-9]+)($|&) [NC]
```

A small addition here is the `?:` after the opening parenthesis. This makes the capturing group (as denoted by the surrounding parentheses) *non-capturing*, so we can still use `%1` (and not `%2`) in the *substitution* string to reference the `id` URL parameter value.

The complete rule then becomes:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:^|&)id=(\d+)($|&) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /?p=%1 [R=301,L]
```

`\d` (shorthand character class) is the same as `[0-9]`.

NB: You should test first with a 302 (temporary) redirect and make sure the browser cache is cleared before testing.

Needless to say, this rule needs to go near the top of the root `.htaccess` file.